Vega-lite value based text at the latest date
I'm trying to adapt the case from below to show instead of symbols, the price as text in the graph.
Every time I change the code to switch from symbol to price the values got repeated for each month.
Any idea how to overcome this?
Vega-lite doucemntation(https://i.sstatic.net/26v28vM6.png)
enter image description here
Already tried to simply replace the symbol with the price field

Please add an example of the code you have used using vega editor. Also read the transform documentation here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/joinaggregate.html

According to documentation joinaggregate could be replaced with the argmin/max.
Here you can find a link with the code in vega-lite editor.
Line chart
